# Ionic 2 - OneSignal - Obter player_id

Tags: ionic2, api

Eu uso o OneSignal para notificações push em uma aplicação ionic 2.
Para enviar as notificações direcionadas à usuários específicos eu preciso recuperar o player_id do OneSignal.

Alguém tem ideia de como recuperar esse id da plataforma?

Comment: Você tá usando o plugin do `ionicnative`?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei como fazer para recuperar o player_id do plugin OneSignal, e na verdade é bem simples.
No app.component.ts, adicionei o código:

```
  window["plugins"].OneSignal.getIds(ids => {
    console.log("player_id: " + ids.userId);
  });
```

Com isso, consigo o PLAYER ID do usuário, possibilitando, por exemplo, o envio de notificações push direcionadas ao usuário em específico.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. E esse método roda assim que a aplicação ionic é iniciada o que já permite guardar esse número e mandar para o seu backend, como foi o meu caso. Assim, minha api processa a solicitação e já devolve para o dispositivo.